# Load balancing/Proxy backend with data across locations

Tags: load-balancing, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I am looking into a setup where I will have servers and databases in multiple regions (data not replicated across region but independent).

The ideal flow would be:
 - user make a request to api.domain.com
 - proxy/load balancer determines which location contains the user data / user related data (ideally cache this against the user's session)
 - proxy routes the request to location1.api.domain.com
 - ideally the location1.api.domain.com will be load balanced through this service too, or independently (AWS Beanstalk for example)

I am looking at HAProxy which seems to support custom routing but do you have any tips around a setup like this or some articles/examples of custom routing? If that's a good solution for this at all.

Related question advising to use HAProxy:
[How to configure reverse proxy/loadbalancer for custom routing](https://serverfault.com/questions/190477/how-to-configure-reverse-proxy-loadbalancer-for-custom-routing)

Answer (score 0):

HAProxy would certainly work. I have had great luck doing this with Nginx and Lua in the past. I prefer this approach for the near infinite flexibility. Unfortunately there isn't a basic service for this type of need since you will be looking at custom data to make your routing decisions.

So, if you prefer HAProxy I say go for it. If you would like additional flexibility then go with Nginx and Lua.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After more research I went with Nginx with Lua (Openresty). It does offer great flexibility and seems to be efficient for the job.